Danted: Unable to receive intial socks response
I try to setup a socks proxy server with an aws lightsail server ubuntu. I installed
sudo apt install dante-server

updated the config
logoutput: syslog
internal: ens5 port = 1080 
external: IPv4.OF.MY.SERVER
socksmethod: pam
user.privileged: proxy
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
    from: DYNAMIC.IP.1.0/24 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect
}

client pass {
    from: DYNAMIC.IP.2.0/24 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect
}

socks pass {
    from: DYNAMIC.IP.1.0/24 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect
}

socks pass {
    from: DYNAMIC.IP.2.0/24 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect
}

and started the service, made sure it's running and active
sudo systemctl start danted
sudo systemctl status danted

neither remote request from ip whitelist nor local curl test works, for localtest:
curl --socks5 username:password@localhost:1080 https://example.com

and always end up a
Unable to receive intial socks response

for remote access (I have made sure credentials are properly set and working)
curl --socks5 username:password@MY.SERVER.IP:1080 https://example.com

curl: (97) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I made sure prot is added and validated by
sudo netstat -tuln | grep 1080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

danted -v
Dante v1.4.2.  Copyright (c) 1997 - 2014 Inferno Nettverk A/S, Norway

I checked the syslogs of danted every time before and after I try to do something, for example, restarting danted, make a local request, etc.
sudo journalctl -u danted

but all logs show no error
Oct 13 06:43:50 ip-172-26-8-18 systemd[1]: danted.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 13 06:43:50 ip-172-26-8-18 systemd[1]: Stopped SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
Oct 13 06:43:50 ip-172-26-8-18 systemd[1]: danted.service: Consumed 3.071s CPU time.
Oct 13 06:43:50 ip-172-26-8-18 systemd[1]: Starting SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Oct 13 06:43:50 ip-172-26-8-18 systemd[1]: Started SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
Oct 13 06:43:50 ip-172-26-8-18 danted[83664]: info: Dante/server[1/1] v1.4.2 running
Oct 13 07:08:59 ip-172-26-8-18 danted[83664]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Oct 13 07:08:59 ip-172-26-8-18 systemd[1]: Stopping SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...

then I tried to reinstall danted and go again, the same result.
danted has been driving me crazy, I will be more than grateful if u can give me a hand
